# Why doesn't HashMap.merged work on Map

Tags: scala

Why doesn't HashMap.merged work on Map? For example like this:

```
    val resultMap = collection.immutable.HashMap[String, Int]()
    val justMap =  collection.immutable.Map[String, Int]()
    resultMap.merged(justMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

The types does not match, check the [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashMap). Use `++` operator instead:

```
val firstMap = collection.immutable.HashMap[String, Int]()
val secondMap =  collection.immutable.Map[String, Int]()
val resultMap = firstMap ++ secondMap
```